# Iterating over array inside object in JSX giving undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I am fetching data from my API :

```
  fetch('/api/p/' + project_id).then(res => res.json())
            .then((project) => {
                console.log(project)
                this.setState({ project })
            }
            );
```

the project structur is like this :

```
{
 name: "project1",
comments: ["com1", "com2"]
}
```

now inside my return function, I need to Loop through all comments and render them sparetly each comment on a different row so I used this code:

```
this.state.project.comments.map((comment) => {
           return (
               <p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> { comment } </p>
          );
 });
```

I am getting this Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I tried map or forEach and for. and also I can't get its length because I get the same error.

but if I type `this.state.project.comments` I get all elements in one row without space like this `comment1comment2comment3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `.map` on a value that's `undefined`.  It's probably because `this.state.project.comments` isn't defined while you're `fetch`ing, but React is still trying to do the initial render.

Make sure you set an initial state somewhere, like

```js
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = { project: { comments: [] } };
}
```

Alternatively, you can give a default value right there when you call `.map`:

```js
(this.state.project.comments || []).map((comment) => {
```

Comment: thank u, this solved the problem .. I think it is being undefined for a bit only

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mapping over the wrong this, this line:
`this.state.comments.map((comment) => {`
should be
`this.state.project.comments.map((comment) => {`

Comment: I fixed , not like that

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from your code is that you are mapping the 'comments' but you are updating the project and that too you have to like

```
this.setState({
  project: res.data
})
```

and for mapping the data

```
this.state.project.map((project)=>{
   return (
               <p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i> { project.comments } </p>
          );
})
```

Comment: project is an object, not array